# Decompositions of $\partial_i$ to the radial direction and rotations in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

We know in dimension $3$,
\begin{align} 
 \partial_{i}= \frac{x_i}{r} \partial_{r} -  \varepsilon_{ijk} \frac{x^j}{r} \frac{R^k}{r} ,
\end{align}
where $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ are Levi-Civita symbols and
\begin{align}
 x_i:=\delta_{ij}x^j , \quad  R^k:=  \varepsilon^{klq} x_l\partial_{q} .
\end{align}

I wonder if there is an analog in higher dimension $n$ (for $n \geq 4$) that can also be written in a simple form like this one?